# Python: filter and generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n + 2
        yield n
def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x % n > 0
def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
        n = next(it) 
        yield n
        it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)
for n in primes():
    if n < 10:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

1. I want to know what is the process about this practice , i was stuck on the

```
it = _odd_iter()
```

and

```
it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)
```

Is the **it** stored value like list or something?

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: `it` is not a list, it is a generator object. You can iterate over a generator object just like you can over a list, but (in contrast to the list) only once.

Comment: `it` is like an imaginary list. (It occupies no memory... other than the reference to object and the method used to construct it.)

Comment: I use this Websit:[process](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit)

I have question about step 30 to 31 , the `it` change from **generator instance**

to **filter instance** , so why does step 32 `n = next(it)` would call `_odd_iter():` ?

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, filter() returns a filter object(which is an iterator) and not a list

```
>>> filter(lambda x : x < 5 , [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
<filter object at 0x7eff8b5922e8>
>>> list(filter(lambda x : x < 5 , [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can check [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for more information. This is only in Python3.

The second part is similar. filter() will iterate through the generator and create another iterator which contains the filtered data.